# Group Dispatcher.Invoke in the same function

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

How can I group a number of **Dispatcher.Invoke** and wait for one group to finished before running the following group?

Take following for example, the first group creates two threads that runs concurrently. After both threads are done, the second group of threads starts, and so forth.

```
private void FooMethod()
{
    // First group
    dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo), cmd1A);
    dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo), cmd1B);

    // Second group
    dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo), cmd2A);
    dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo), cmd2B);

    // Third group
    dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo), cmd3A);
    dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo), cmd3B);

    ....
}
```

Comment: please have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824967/how-to-properly-wait-for-multiple-threads-that-call-dispatcher-invoke-to-finish

Comment: i have looked at the post you refer... but it is a mess to understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper class around dispatcher with queue to handle groups. The code may be messy, but it should deliver the general idea:

```
public class DispatcherGroup
{
    private List<Action> _delegates;
    private List<object[]> _parameters;
    private ManualResetEvent _isFinished;

    public void Add(Action toInvoke, params object[] parameters)
    {
        _delegates.Add(toInvoke);
        _parameters.Add(parameters);
    }

    public void Invoke(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        List<DispatcherOperation> operations = new List<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < _delegates.Length; i++)
        {
            DispatcherOperation operation = dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_delegates[i], _parameters[i]);
            operations.Add(operation);
        }

        // check status of all operations before completion
    }

}

public class DispatcherGroupInvoker
{
    private Queue<DispatcherGroup> _groups;
    public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get;set;}
    public void Invoke()
    {
        while (!_groups.Count != 0)
        {
            DispatcherGroup group = _groups.Dequeue();
            group.Invoke(Dispatcher);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you add some explanation? cannot follow the code. Also, where is the class for DispatcherOperation?

Comment: You create groups to call by adding necessary actions and parameters. From your example - delegates cmd1A, cmd1B with no parameters - is a first group; and so on.

Then you add those group to groupInvoker (forgot the add method). 
Then you call GroupInvoker.Invoke which invokes groups one by one. Every groups waits for all the delegates to finish processing via DispatcherOperation.Status.

Comment: + 1 thanks for the effort. But I completely do not understand what you're saying.

Comment: I'll post usage example eventually. :)